# Ubuntu 14.04 + Lenovo Mouse N700

Tags: 14.04, mouse, bluetooth, lenovo

I have recently updated my dual boot of Windows 8.1 with Ubuntu 14.04.

I have a Lenovo Mouse N700, which works fine when connected using Wireless USB Dongle.
However, when I try to connect using Bluetooth, it fails.

Ubuntu Bluetooth options shows the Lenovo Mouse N700 as a device found but with TYPE UNKNOWN. I tried several times, but Ubuntu never recognize it as a mouse type.

I cannot use the Wireless USB connection option as my laptop has only 1 USB port which I need for other purposes.

Hopefully somebody can give a valuable input how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think is is a problem with BlueZ and Bluetooth 4.0 low power devices.

This past week I tried the Microsoft Arc Touch mouse which is Bluetooth 4.0
and although it would pair its type showed up as Unknown and obviously was not useable as a mouse.

I then bought & tried the Lenovo N700 which again is Bluetooth 4.0 and same problem as the Microsoft Mouse.

Note an older Bluetooth 2.0 mouse still works just fine.

There have been several bugs filed about the need to get Bluez v5.x into the Ubuntu repositories as from what I could find... Bluez 5.x has support for the low energy Bluetooth 4.0 devices.

Comment: Hi bmullan,
How did you install Bluez 5.x.
While installing ( 1st step ./configure) I get below error
configure: error: libudev >= 172 is required
I am not able to install libudev at all.
I tried synaptic, software update center. Nothing works. it says the website is not accessible
http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_204-5ubuntu20.7_amd64.deb

Answer (score 1):

First try disable GATT experimental extension into the

`/etc/default/bluetooth`

`NOPLUGIN_OPTION="-E"`

Restar bluetooth service.

`sudo systemctl start bluetooth.service`

just had to pair and trust the mouse manually using the "bluetoothctl" console and it worked fine.

```
# bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# list
Controller <controller mac> BlueZ 5.5 [default]
[bluetooth]# select <controller mac>
[bluetooth]# power on
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# agent on
[bluetooth]# devices
Device <mouse mac> Name: Bluetooth Mouse
[bluetooth]# pair <mouse mac>
[bluetooth]# trust <mouse mac>
[bluetooth]# connect <mouse mac>
```

Answer (score 0):

First try to find your bluetooth in additional drives, if it won't help you have to find your bluetooth driver and install it from oem's site. If you don't know the id of your bluetoot (most probably it's together with your wireless card) by entering`sudo lshw`

Comment: Hi Biozalp,Where can I find Bluetooth additional driver. At Lenvo's site the drivers are only available for windows OS.  Moreover my bluetooth is working as I am able to connect to my phone. Also, my mouse is visible in the bluetooth option but recognized as unknown device.